# Is it possible to write on memory that was moved away using memmove in C?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, memmove

I'm sorry if my code is garbage but I wanted to experiment with string manipulation on an already dynamically allocated string without losing my original pointer so that when I do go ahead and free up the memory outside of the function I won't be freeing the wrong thing.

The algorithm is as follows:

- Receive a dynamically allocated string containing multiple words
- If there is an even number of words, set the amount of spaces between each word to 2.
  Otherwise leave it as 1 space.

```
    char* evenNumOfWords(char* str)
{
    int spaceCounter = 0; // count the occurrences of space
    int spaceIndices[strlen(str)]; // save the index of all space characters to avoid going through the whole array twice
    char* endPointer = str + strlen(str);
    int length;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < strlen(str) ; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == ' ')
        {
            spaceIndices[spaceCounter] = i;
            spaceCounter++;
        }
    }
    if (spaceCounter % 2 == 1) { // if there is an odd number of spaces there's an even number of words
        for (int i = 0 ; i < spaceCounter ; i++)
        {
            length = (int)(endPointer - str);
            memmove(str + spaceIndices[i] * sizeof(char) + 1, str + spaceIndices[i] * sizeof(char), length - spaceIndices[i] + 1); // move the string 1 byte forward starting from the place where there's a space
            endPointer++;
            str[spaceIndices[i]] = ' ';
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Perhaps my logic is entirely incorrect but my main question is, can I actually write on the memory that I moved my data away from with memmove? Because I'm getting "code 138 (interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS)" which after Googling I found it's caused by writing on non-writable memory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try better formatting your coda and commenting it , it's hard to read

Comment: Fixed it, didn't see until it was published - thanks :)

Comment: ```void* memmove(void* str1, const void* str2, size_t n)``` only ```copies``` n characters from str2 to str1 and return a pointer to ```str1```. Most probably you had defined a ```const char*``` somewhere which is in section ```rodata``` and tried to cast it to ```char*``` and in your code, write into it which fails.

Comment: Does the buffer passed in contain room for the extra spaces inserted between words? If not, there is a possibility of overrunning the buffer. Is the function allowed to reallocate the dynamically allocated buffer to the correct size?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: You are using `str` as if there is enough usable memory after its last byte.

Comment: it does contain enough space, i've malloc'd 60 bytes for this test string.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between `memmove` and `memcpy` is that `memmove` copies the bytes non destructively. That is to say, if the source and destination areas overlap, `memmove` will work fine but `memcpy` may not.

Your problem is likely due to passing a constant string into your function. If you do

```
foo = evenNumOfWords("the cat sat on the mat");
```

the string passed in is a literal and likely to be located in a read only segment.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few edits thanks to suggestions from you guys, thanks a lot.

For starters I changed

```
spaceIndices[spaceCounter] = i;
```

to

```
spaceIndices[spaceCounter] = i + spaceCounter;
```

then I went ahead and made the function void because I didn't need any return considering I'm passing the string by reference and it's altering it directly from the heap (maybe I'm using the wrong terminology don't crucify me)

And I went ahead and scanned the strings in the console using fgets instead of passing in a string that was pre-baked in the code

To answer my own question, yes you can definitely write on memory that was moved using memmove.